# Using Python to query from two tables in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Currently using below code to get data from one table with the given `WHERE` & `AND` conditions:

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=XYZ\DA202P;'
                      'Database=Reporting;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = pd.read_sql("""
               SELECT PID,NewValue,OriginalValue FROM Inc.ProblemAu
               where (ModifiedDate >= '2019-06-01 00:00:00.000' and ModifiedDate <= '2019-06-21 23:59:59.99')
               AND (NewValue='ntfy')
                """,conn)
query.to_excel('c:/temp/pydbc.xlsx')
```

There is another table Inc.Problem with colums PID, X,y,z that I need to get, if the PID results from above code running on Inc.ProblemAu. The results from above code can contain duplicates of PIDs but unique values in other columns.

How do I get the data(x,y,z columns) from second table Inc.Problem based on all Unique PID values generated from above code?

Comment: One possible approach would be to do the initial SELECT into a temporary table, e.g., `cursor.execute("SELECT PID, NewValue, OriginalValue INTO #temp FROM Inc.ProblemAu WHERE ... ")`, then dump the first .xlsx using a DataFrame created from `SELECT * FROM #temp` and the second .xlsx using a DataFrame created from `SELECT PID, x, y, z FROM Inc.Problem WHERE PID IN (SELECT PID FROM #temp)`.

Comment: @GordThompson ... why do you need to dump to temp table or Excel? Why not run `IN` between `SELECT` statements?

Comment: @Parfait - The question isn't really clear on what they want to do with the information from the second table. I tossed out the option of using the temp table as one way of getting the information separately without effectively running the first query twice. As for Excel, they're dumping the first query out to Excel so I figured they'd want to do that for the other table, too.

Comment: @Parfait from second table, I need additinal rows xyz to calculate some details, which I need to do once I have a final output from both tables. rows are not expected to go beyond 1-2k and I only have read access to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use an `IN`, `EXISTS` or `JOIN` clauses:

**`IN`**

```sql
SELECT PID, x, y, z 
FROM Inc.Problem
WHERE PID IN
  (SELECT PID
   FROM Inc.ProblemAu
   WHERE (ModifiedDate >= '2019-06-01 00:00:00.000' 
     AND  ModifiedDate <= '2019-06-21 23:59:59.99')
     AND (NewValue='ntfy')
  )
```

**`EXISTS`**

```sql
SELECT PID, x, y, z 
FROM Inc.Problem main
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
   FROM Inc.ProblemAu sub
   WHERE (sub.ModifiedDate >= '2019-06-01 00:00:00.000' 
     AND  sub.ModifiedDate <= '2019-06-21 23:59:59.99')
     AND (sub.NewValue='ntfy')
     AND main.PID = sub.PID
  )
```

**`JOIN`**

```sql
SELECT main.PID, main.x, main.y, main.z 
FROM Inc.Problem main
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT PID
   FROM Inc.ProblemAu sub
   WHERE (ModifiedDate >= '2019-06-01 00:00:00.000' 
     AND  ModifiedDate <= '2019-06-21 23:59:59.99')
     AND (NewValue='ntfy')
  ) sub
ON main.PID = sub.PID
```

Comment: does this work only with read access?  Is DISTINCT is the part where it excludes duplicates?

Comment: These are all valid SQL Server queries so should run in `read_sql`. All of these should render equivalent outputs and to only filter *Inc.Problem* records bringing in no other records. `DISTINCT` is only needed for `JOIN` to avoid multiple matches. Please test and see.

Comment: This solution solves your posted need *get the data(x,y,z columns) from second table Inc.Problem based on all Unique PID values generated from above code*.

Comment: I tried to run the query on Sql Server directly before using it on my Python code. but I keep getting the below message o SSMS

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXISTS'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.

Comment: JOIN

SELECT PID, x, y, z 

the PID was also showing ambiguous column name and thats when I realized In.Problem also has ModifiedDate column. So thats more than 1 column with same name. I tried adding table names before each column but it says multipart identified could not be found even though I added correct name (ex:Inc.Problem.PID, Inc.Problem.ClosedByELID etc)

Comment: Again, these are all valid SQL Server 2014 queries as this reproducible, [rextester example](https://rextester.com/BIAW35517) demonstrates. See how all three versions return same records. You are correct with ambiguous column with `JOIN` version which simply required adding an alias in `SELECT`: `main.PID`.